# Filtering array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays, and in each array they date and a random value.

I have a date picker, and once I clicked on a date I am holding on the value of that date.

So example

```
var array = [ ["02-01-2017 09:20:21", 116],
    ["02-13-2017 19:07:57", 133],
    ["01-28-2017 10:27:15", 29],
    ["02-14-2017 06:56:22", 137],
    ["02-22-2017 09:23:43", 208],
    ["01-15-2017 23:33:40", 120],
    ["01-16-2017 05:21:05", 146],
    ["01-02-2017 01:49:32", 209],
    ["02-14-2017 06:19:54", 172],
    ["01-02-2017 02:12:16", 13],
    ["02-25-2017 11:39:00", 213],
    ["01-01-2017 15:27:43", 39],
    ["01-10-2017 17:58:27", 96],
    ["02-10-2017 18:17:42", 99],
    ["01-04-2017 21:28:33", 40],
    ["02-08-2017 18:09:55", 92],
    ["02-08-2017 10:24:47", 12],
    ["02-03-2017 19:49:59", 15],
    ["01-07-2017 16:52:17", 196]
]
```

so once I click on a date from my datepicker like 02-08-2017 I want to filter out my big array so at the end my array only has arrays that include the selected date.

```
var newArray = [
        ["02-08-2017 18:09:55", 92],
        ["02-08-2017 10:24:47", 12]
]
```

so how do I do that? not using any jquery

Comment: What have you tried so far? Filtering an array is a [rather basic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) task in JavaScript.

Comment: "has arrays that in" In what? Did you forget something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want Array.prototype.filter which takes a function and applies it to each element of an array. If the function returns true, the element it was passed will be returned as its result.

For example:

```
let result = sourceArray.filter((elt) => elt[0].match(/^02-08-2017$/))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, sadly my mistake was stupid, what I was 
    let allDays =  array.filter(picked => picked.match(day))

so the parenthesis and not targeting the index mess me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter and transform the strings in Date() object and use toDateString() to compare them ignoring the hours and considering only the date

```js
var array = [ ["02-01-2017 09:20:21", 116], ["02-13-2017 19:07:57", 133], ["01-28-2017 10:27:15", 29], ["02-14-2017 06:56:22", 137], ["02-22-2017 09:23:43", 208], ["01-15-2017 23:33:40", 120], ["01-16-2017 05:21:05", 146], ["01-02-2017 01:49:32", 209], ["02-14-2017 06:19:54", 172], ["01-02-2017 02:12:16", 13],  ["02-25-2017 11:39:00", 213], ["01-01-2017 15:27:43", 39], ["01-10-2017 17:58:27", 96], ["02-10-2017 18:17:42", 99], ["01-04-2017 21:28:33", 40], ["02-08-2017 18:09:55", 92], ["02-08-2017 10:24:47", 12], ["02-03-2017 19:49:59", 15], ["01-07-2017 16:52:17", 196] ]

const selectedDate = "02-08-2017";
const transformedDate = new Date(selectedDate).toDateString()

const result = array.filter(el => new Date(el[0]).toDateString() === transformedDate)

console.log(result)
```